# sometimes I can access to id of my html tag sometimes not

Tags: javascript, html, dataset

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmTlw.png)I want to get access to data-id linked to my icons to use them to manipulate the section related to these ids

but the problem is when I press the icons sometimes o get undefined sometimes its works I don't know why

please explain to me what I did wrong.

```
  <body class="main-content">
    <header class="section sec1 header active" id="home"></header>
    <main>
      <section class="section sec2 about" id="about"></section>
      <section class="section sec3 portfolio" id="portfolio"></section>
      <section class="section sec4 contact" id="contact"></section>
    </main>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="control control-1 active-btn" data-id="home">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="control control-2" data-id="about">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="control control-3" data-id="portfolio">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-briefcase"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="control control-4" data-id="contact">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-address-book"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is the javascript

```
let active = document.querySelectorAll(".control");
let allsections = document.querySelectorAll(".main-content");
let section = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
function makingActive() {
  active.forEach((e) => {
    e.addEventListener("click", () => {
      let active_1 = document.querySelectorAll(".active-btn");
      active_1.forEach((e) => {
        e.classList.remove("active-btn");
      });
      e.classList.add("active-btn");
    });
  });
  allsections.forEach((e) => {
    e.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      const id = e.target.dataset.id;
      console.log(id);
      section.forEach((sec) => {
        sec.classList.remove("active");
      });
      const secActive = document.getElementById(id);
      secActive.classList.add("active");
    });
  });
}

makingActive();
```

Comment: please post all your revelant code to the problem, a lot of code missing

Comment: how do i edit my question

Comment: there is an edit button right at the end of your question

Comment: is it fine like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```js
const allSections = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.section'))
const allControls = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.control'))

allSections.forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const id = e.target.dataset.id
    const secActive = document.getElementById(id)
    
    console.clear()
    console.log('id:', id)
    
    allControls.forEach((sec) => {
      sec.classList.remove('active')
    })
    secActive.classList.add('active')
  })
})
```

```css
.section {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}

.controls {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header class="section sec1 header" data-id="home">Home</header>
<main>
  <section class="section sec2 about" data-id="about">About</section>
  <section class="section sec3 portfolio" data-id="portfolio">Portfolio</section>
  <section class="section sec4 contact" data-id="contact">Contact</section>
</main>
<div class="controls">
  <div class="control control-1 active-btn active" id="home">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i> -> home
  </div>
  <div class="control control-2" id="about">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i> -> about
  </div>
  <div class="control control-3" id="portfolio">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-briefcase"></i> -> portfolio
  </div>
  <div class="control control-4" id="contact">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-address-book"></i> -> contact
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much 
but why mine didn't work

Comment: You are trying to access `classList` on `undefined` variable